# Pass data between laravel and vuejs2 component

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2

I have tried this

```
 <div id="keybrandsapp">
    <profile :userdata="'{!! json_encode($user) !!}'"></profile>
 </div>
```

NB: $user is passed from the laravel controller when requesting for profile view that is

```
public function profile(){
    $user = Auth::user();

    return \view('user.profile', compact('user', $user));

 }
```

In my profile component(vuejs code)

```
    export default {
    props: ['userdata'],
    mounted() {
        console.dir(this.userdata)

    }
}
```

But this doesnt pass the user data but prints it on the screen.

How do i pass the userdata from laravel blade to vuejs component.

Comment: I'm not a fan of vuejs, how about making a request from vuejs to fetch current user `/yourserver.com/user` instead of  showing the data on page

Comment: ` :userdata="'{!! json_encode($user) !!}'"` why are you putting the single quotes between the double quotes and how about using just `:userdata="{{json_encode($user)}}`

Comment: @MerhawiFissehaye I see my stupid mistake now the data is getting passed.

Answer (score 2):

What I suggest is to call the request from the Vuejs template rather than trying to load the data directly into the Html. So the steps will be

1. Blade loads Vuejs component (at this step you are not getting a user data yet)
2. component make a request to get user data
3. component process a returned data

Comment: Exactly what I suggested in my comment above. Displaying json object on page is not cool, even if its hidden behind html.

Comment: @Digitlimit while I was typing my answer, this question had 0 comments :) It is, of course, possible to do the way it is stated in a question, however it is not recommended